# return row ID values back to One

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, primary-key

i have entered some testing  values and include my current values in my access database..since my form working fine and ready to go live,i delete some of my test values in my database.ID is increment which i fine but how can i return my ID back to 1 and re-enter my current values again..example if i delete my row id 1 in my database my row ID 2 value become my first value it doesn't not change to ID 1..all i want if i delete row 1, as ID 1, my row 2 values should be my ID=1 it should change automatically..

Answer (score 1):

Delete all of the rows in the table with the AutoNumber column and then **Compact and Repair** the database from within the Access application. That will reset the AutoNumber counter back to 1.